# SQL Server 2005 - Dynamic insert query issue

Tags: sql-server-2005

I'm struggling to get this statement run

```
SET @SelectStatement = 'INSERT INTO [ArchiveProcessHistory] VALUES (' + @TableName + ',' + @TotalRowsSource +',' + @TotalRowsDestination + ',' + GetDate()') '
```

[I know something is wrong with the above statment, which I'm not able to fix)

```
SET @FullStatement = @SelectStatement
```

ArchiveProcessHistory Table Structure is:

```
TableName - nvarch(5)
TotalRowsSource - integer
TotalRowsDestination - integer
DateofInsert - Date
```

It's giving me this error when i run through sp_executesql

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure usp_ArchiveTable, Line 39
>   Incorrect syntax near ') '.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

```
SET @SelectStatement = 'INSERT INTO [ArchiveProcessHistory] VALUES (' + @TableName + ',' + @TotalRowsSource +',' + @TotalRowsDestination + ',' + GetDate() + ') '
```

Missing one `+` after `getdate()`.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid a potential SQL Injection attack you could use [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) instead.

```
declare @SelectStatement nvarchar(max)

set @SelectStatement = 
  'INSERT INTO [ArchiveProcessHistory] VALUES
    (@TableName, @TotalRowsSource, @TotalRowsDestination, GetDate())'

exec sp_executesql @SelectStatement,
                   N'@TableName nvarchar(5), @TotalRowsSource int, @TotalRowsDestination int',
                   @TableName = '123', 
                   @TotalRowsSource = 4, 
                   @TotalRowsDestination = 5
```

You should also have a look at [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

Comment: +1 - *if* dynamic SQL is truly required (not clear from the question if there is any need for it), use parameterised SQL like this

Comment: But these are @TableName  are input parameters which are passed to stored procredure.

Comment: @ConradJagger You don't use it as a table name in your query. If you do, you should concatenate the table name into `@SelectStatement` using [`quotename()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of GetDate() in your insert statement which is a function, use current_timestamp.

```
SET @SelectStatement = 'INSERT INTO [ArchiveProcessHistory] VALUES (' + @TableName + ','   + @TotalRowsSource +',' + @TotalRowsDestination + ',' + current_timestamp + ') '
```

Comment: This is failing because TableName is VARCHAR ... and above statement fails when I run it... varchar error